# Set x and y values of place method at runtime

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm developing a way to position widgets at runtime using tkinter's place() method, to make it easier to configure a form with entries, for example.

I made a test code and it doesn't work very well. Stick with a skipping widget in the window.

The code is this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

list_pos = [[20, 20]]

def move(event):
    list_pos[0][0] = event.x + 10
    list_pos[0][1] = event.y + 10
    #print(list_pos[0][0], list_pos[0][1])
    b1.place(x=list_pos[0][0], y=list_pos[0][1])

root = tk.Tk()
b1 = ttk.Button(root, text="OK")
b1.place(x=list_pos[0][0], y=list_pos[0][1])
b1.bind('<B1-Motion>', move)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I did not understand "Stick with a skipping widget in the window." until running the code, corrected with indents so it would run.  I think you meant "I am stuck...".  If one clicks outside the button, the code works better with 'root.bind' instead of 'b1.bind'.  If one puts the button in a frame, then only clicks inside/outside the button have effect, depending on whether one binds the button or frame.  I am not sure what is best to do.

Comment: Thank you Terry. With your guidance using root.bind() it became better to move the button. Now I'm going to work on developing to choose which widget to move in the window.
Thanks

Comment: What does "doesn't work very well" mean? What do you expect it to do, and how is that different from what it's actually doing?

Comment: The way I did, when I drag the button and it moves in small jumps. This is what I wanted to say. Thanks.

Comment: Select which widget to move by binding each widget to `move`, as you did for `b1`, and then using the proper move function given in Davis Herring's answer, possibly modified as I suggested in a comment thereto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event coordinates are relative to the widget on which the **event** is reported, but widget coordinates are relative to the **parent** widget, so it is wrong to use one to set the other (with or without a constant offset like the `+ 10` here).  Instead, convert one to the other:

```
def move(event):
  w=event.widget
  w.place(x=event.x+w.winfo_x(), y=event.y+w.winfo_y())
```

*Then* add whatever desired offset, perhaps from the **click** location to get a smooth start.

Comment: Also, the event object has `x_root` and `y_root` attributes which give you the coordinate of the event relative to the root window.

Comment: @BryanOakley: That’s certainly useful, but the parent might not be the root.

Comment: Perfect Davis Herring. Thank you very much.

Comment: lf one adds `anchor='center'` as the first argument of `w.place`, then on first movement, the widget jumps to put the center of the widget, rather than the upper right ('nw') corner of the widget, under the 'tip' of the mouse pointer.  I find this more intuitive and easier for moving the widget around.